# Implementing operator precedence in my calculator interpreter

Tags: ruby, interpreter, operator-precedence

As part of learning Ruby am trying to implement a basic interpreter which reads input and do basic arithmetic calculations. So far basic arithmetic operations are working but having problem in operator precedence. Which is not handled yet. This is the code. Am at a beginner level. Any mistakes in this code are due to my lack of knowledge. How this code can be modified to handle operator precedence.
Sample output

```
2+2+2 = 6 #correct
10+10/2 = 10 # incorrect as in irb answer must be 15
```

[Github Repo of this interpreter](https://github.com/pckrishnadas88/ruby-interpreter)

```
=begin
Basic calculator Interpreter
can add, substract, multiply , divide with any number of operands at a time
Drawback : Lacks operator precedence
=end
class Interpreter   
    attr_accessor :input
    def initialize
        @input = gets.chomp             
    end 
    def intepret        
        first_operand  = []     
        f              = []     
        operator       = '+'        
        array          = Array.new      
        lc             = 0

        @input.split.join.split("").each_with_index.map do |i, index|

            if i.is_number?
                first_operand.push(i)   
                if index == @input.length-1                     
                    array.push(first_operand.join("").to_i)                 
                end
            elsif i.is_plus?                
                f = first_operand
                first_operand = nil
                first_operand = []              
                array.push(f.join("").to_i)
                array.push("+")
            elsif i.is_minus?           
                f = first_operand
                first_operand = nil
                first_operand = []              
                operator = '-'              
                array.push(f.join("").to_i)
                array.push("-")
            elsif i.is_multi?               
                f = first_operand
                first_operand = nil
                first_operand = []              
                operator = '*'              
                array.push(f.join("").to_i)
                array.push("*")
            elsif i.is_divide?              
                f = first_operand
                first_operand = nil
                first_operand = []              
                operator = '/'              
                array.push(f.join("").to_i)
                array.push("/")
            else
                puts "Illegal input exiting.."
                exit            
            end             

            lc = lc+1

        end     
        #apply the appropriate operation on the inputs based on the operand         
        #puts "=======TOKENS======"     
        #puts array.inspect 
        result = 0
        array.each_with_index.map do |x, key|
            result = x if key == 0          
            if x == '+'
                if key == 0 
                    result = add(result, array[key+1])
                else
                    result = add(result, array [key+1])
                end
            elsif x == '-'
                if key == 0 
                    result = minus(result, array[key+1])
                else
                    result = minus(result, array [key+1])
                end
            elsif x == '*'
                if key == 0 
                    result = multi(result, array[key+1])
                else
                    result = multi(result, array [key+1])
                end 
            elsif x == '/'
                begin
                    if key == 0 
                        result = divide(result, array[key+1])
                    else
                        result = divide(result, array [key+1])
                    end 
                rescue
                    puts "Zero Divsion error"
                    exit
                end  
            end 
        end
        puts "Result is: "+result.to_s
    end 
    def print_token(type, value)
        puts type + ' '+ value
    end
    def add(f,s)
        return f.to_i + s.to_i
    end
    def minus(f,s)
        return f.to_i - s.to_i
    end
    def multi(f,s)
        return f.to_i * s.to_i
    end
    def divide(f,s)
        return f.to_i / s.to_i
    end
end
# Override the string class, to directly use methods like obj.is_number? rather than is_number?(obj)
class String
  def is_number?
    true if Float(self) rescue false
  end
  def is_plus?
    true if self == '+' rescue false
  end
  def is_minus?
    true if self == '-' rescue false
  end
  def is_multi?
    true if self == '*' rescue false
  end
  def is_divide?
    true if self == '/' rescue false
  end
end
#continue accepting inputs until exit CTRL + D
while true
    print 'pck>:'
    i_obj = Interpreter.new
    i_obj.intepret
end
```

Comment: All your String query methods, except for `is_number?` can be simplified to `self == 'operator'`, since they won't give an error, and you can safely remove the `rescue`.

Comment: @SilverPhoenix thanks for the help, but this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, process the input using the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm). This should give a list of tokens in [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) (RPN). Then you can evaluate the RPN expression.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it came up first on Google and the accepted answer really did not give me what I was looking for.

What I believe the original poster is looking for is called a recursive descent parser. Basically implementing a parser that recursively solves itself. To understand lets look at the grammar for what we are trying to do.

```
EXPR: factor(add|sub factor)*
FACTOR: number
```

If we update the grammar to put number to be either a number or a left right parentheses we can solve the problem simply:

```
EXPR: factor(add|sub factor)*
FACTOR: number | lparen expr rparen
```

This way if we come across a paren we simply solve the expression within and then return its results. Thus we recursively call EXPR.

This is explained in more detail with code here,
Blog: https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part5/
Code: https://github.com/rspivak/lsbasi/blob/master/part6/calc6.py#L126-L136