# How can I calculate more than 1 operation?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm just starting with C# and I wish to do more than 1 calculation at a time (I'm creating a basic calculator).

I was using this tutorial (I know it’s rather old, but it works still and my calculator actually calculates, But I don’t know how to allow it to calculate more than 1 operation, and it can only do single operations like 1 / 2 or 3 x 5 ): https://www.instructables.com/id/Creating-a-Calculator-Visual-Studio-C/

So I understand the basic concept, it holds your first number in a hidden variable, deletes it from the input variable, your operator ( `- +` whatever) is then put in a second hidden variable and finally your final number is added to the sequence, They are all merged in the operation and calculated, and output back to the input box in the form (I also adjusted the formula a little and a managed to get negative numbers working with it too!).

Here’s the full source code of my project CalcForYou: https://github.com/skylerspark/project-CalcForYou

I handle a numeric click like this:

```
    string input = string.Empty;
    string operand1 = string.Empty;
    string operand2 = string.Empty;
    char operation;
    double result = 0.0;

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.flatTextBox1.Text = "";
        input += "1";
        this.flatTextBox1.Text += input;
    }
```

`+ - / *` click like this:

```
    private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = input;
        operation = '+';
        input = string.Empty;
    }
```

and my equal button:

```
    private void flatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand2 = input;
        double num1, num2;
        double.TryParse(operand1, out num1);
        double.TryParse(operand2, out num2);

        if (operation == '+')
        {
            result = num1 + num2;
            flatTextBox1.Text = "= " + result.ToString();
        }
        else if (operation == '-')
        {
            result = num1 - num2;
            flatTextBox1.Text = "= " + result.ToString();
        }
        else if (operation == '*')
        {
            result = num1 * num2;
            flatTextBox1.Text = "= " + result.ToString();
        }
        else if (operation == '/')
        {
            result = num1 / num2;
            flatTextBox1.Text = "= " + result.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi when asking questions like this, you should provide the relevant code in your questions (not a link to github although that can be useful too). But yes you can do what you're trying to do (although Im unsure of your approach so far as I haven't opened your github project). provide some of your code in the question and you will receive a quicker answer

Comment: @kevin I did provide code though, I added my entire source code.. I got downvoted anyways, I came here a few years back and got question banned in 2 days from downvotes, It’s probably going to happen again anyways... so at this point I guess it doesn’t even matter

Comment: I mean inserting it into the question eg: `my code is visible withou clicking a github link` your link also directed me to github pages and not to your repository. I made an edit for that

Comment: @Furno_Casunate Your code needs to be *in the question*, not linked-to off-site.  We aren't generally interested in looking at entire projects and prefer a [mcve].

Comment: Computing more than one operation requires support for operator precedence.  Which was asked about in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528191/8723329).  Supporting multiple operations in a calculator is not a trivial change to the existing code.  I would suggest looking at the algorithms suggested in the other question, attempting to implement them and then asking a question about a specific problem that you run into.

Comment: Well...I tried to provide an answer, but ultimately bowed to the (correct) pressure to delete my answer. The question is just too broad...and is probably on it's way to being deleted. Consider another site...like quora...for a question like this. Good luck.

Comment: @JonathonK I’m unsure what you mean by operator precedence, I’m new to C#

Comment: @Furno_Casunate `operator precedence` isn't a C# terminology but a math one it means that certain operators have a higher priority than others eg. multiply and devision have a higher priority than addition and subtraction for example `2 + 3 * 4 = 14` because you first need to do `3 * 4 = 12` and only after that add the remaining two `2 + 12 = 14` see this: [click me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2B3*4)